# DNS RCODEs. Unexpected on Remote Machines

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

Could anyone advise on the following entries, please. What does those mean? What is mis-configured here? Please, note that it does not say "resolving errors" or something after refused and serfail. Many thanks for any input!

Unexpected DNS RCODEs:

```
REFUSED:
  169.200.124.94.in-addr.arpa/PTR/IN:
      193.232.130.14#53: 1 Time(s)
  51.42.253.103.in-addr.arpa/PTR/IN:
      103.16.228.32#53: 4 Time(s)
      103.16.228.33#53: 4 Time(s)
SERVFAIL:
  150.232.171.69.dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net/A/IN:
      174.36.198.232#53: 1 Time(s)
  162.7.16.198.dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net/A/IN:
      174.36.198.232#53: 1 Time(s)
  3.1.100.168.dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net/A/IN:
      174.36.198.232#53: 1 Time(s)
```

However, I still cannot seem to get it straight.

- (refused) means that my name server refused to provide information to a requester / or I am the requester here and I was refused?
- (serfail) means that my name server was unable to process the query when clients asked for it / or was I a client here and my query failed?

This is my name server, Bind9 that I run, maintain, and use. These entries come from the logs that Logwatch emails me on a regular basis. The entries in logs for my Bind9 server are generated in my `syslog` file as I haven't created a separate log file for my Bind9 yet. Hope it clarifies your query, Esa. Thank you so much once again and appreciate your help.

The entries look like these to be more exact:

```
named[16567]: error (connection refused) resolving 'zone-ns1.dnswl.org/A/IN': 62.75.191.6#53

named[25211]: error (unexpected RCODE REFUSED) resolving '51.42.253.103.in-addr.arpa/PTR/IN': 103.16.228.32#53

named[25211]: error (unexpected RCODE SERVFAIL) resolving '133.61.208.88.dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net/A/IN': 174.36.198.232#53
```

Answer (score 1):

As specified in [RFC 1035, 4.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-4.1.1), these `RCODE`s are:

> Response code - this 4 bit field is set as part of responses.  The
> values have the following interpretation:
>
> `2` Server failure - The name server was unable to process this query
> due to a problem with the name server.

This migth be a communication error. This is exactly why we have multiple DNS servers, if one is temporarily unavailable. If this is permanent, check network connectivity including firewalls, first. It might also be a configuration error. See your logs for further investigation.

> `5` Refused - The name server refuses to perform the specified
> operation for policy reasons.  For example, a name server may not wish
> to provide the information to the particular requester, or a name
> server may not wish to perform a particular operation (e.g., zone
> transfer) for particular data.

This is most likely an access configuration problem: for some reason you are not allowed to perform the query. In BIND, see options like `allow-query` or in recursive servers `allow-recursion`.

---

A common denominator here is most likely an SMTP server performing DNS based measurements against spam:

- `PTR` queries for `HELO` mismatch checks etc.
- `*.dnsbl.sorbs.net. IN` queries to check against SORBS [Listings](http://www.sorbs.net/listing/aboutlistings.shtml). SORBS may refuse queries if there are too many in too short period. Using *aggregate zones* instead of many separate might help; see [Using SORBS](http://www.sorbs.net/general/using.shtml).

These entries were parsed from the `syslog` file on your *recursive* name server. If there's no error now (confirmed by e.g. `dig 133.61.208.88.dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net @127.0.0.1`), it has probably been temporary. The amount of occasions from 1 to 4 times for each also suggests the same.

It's also possible that the problem was solved immediately by simply moving to the next *authoritative* name server: there should always be at least two, in case one fails. Because by default only the errors gets logged, there wouldn't appear a log line telling you this. You could configure your BIND for more verbose logging, but it's recommend to separate the files per *category*, as some of the categories are really excessive.

The two categories you would be interested now are `resolver` and `queries` (see BIND9 [`logging`](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/logging.html)). Here's my sample BIND9 configuration for logging them under `/var/log/named/`:

```
logging {
    channel resolver_file {
        file "/var/log/named/resolver.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity info;
        print-time yes;
        print-severity yes;
    };
    channel queries_file {
        file "/var/log/named/queries.log" versions 3 size 5m;
        severity info;
        print-time yes;
        print-severity yes;
    };
    category resolver { resolver_file; };
    category queries { queries_file; };
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. Appreciate. Is it seen in these entries where do those errors originate from? Is it on remote servers? When I run various commands and checks on my BIND like dig, dig +search and so on and so forth I always see, "NOERROR" on all of my web-sites.

Comment: I improved my answer to focus more on this exact case.

Comment: @EsaJokinen: Can you please look at the edit, OP create a new account and posted as an answer.

Comment: After getting even more precise details from OP I was now able to make this answer complete.